# Android - Cropping View When Larger Than Device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I'm trying to write a custom view that is draggable and can expand many screens over top of a ListView for highlighting.

The problem I'm running into is when the view is expanded larger than the screen, Android simply stops rendering it. Is there a way to override this?

I've tried changing it's parent's clipChildren, and other similar options, but nothing seems to stop this

I'm changing the height of the view with

```
frame.getLayoutParams().height = /* set the height. */;
frame.requestLayout();
```

then changing the y position of the view with

```
frame.setY( /* set the y position. */ );
```

Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

try

```
LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) frame.getLayoutParams();
params.height = /* set the height. */;

frame.setLayoutParams(params);
frame.requestLayout();
```

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, but setting the height isn't the problem. It works, but when it's larger than it's container, it seems to get cut off by Android.

Comment: Some explanation is recommended. We aim to increase the quality of our answers.